# What is the appropriate design pattern for multiple replacing of specific text or characters

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to replace numeric,html tags, and special characters. I have created a method for each purpose. For example I have created methods for ReplaceSpecialCharacters, ReplaceHTMLTags and ReplaceNumeric. And take note there are some additional replace methods that are coming in. My question is what is the appropriate design pattern for this? I'm thinking of using Strategy or Factory pattern for this, is Decorator pattern applicable for this requirements?

```
sample code
var text="12233333333<body>CLEANTEXT!@#$%^&*()</body>"
var cleanText= ReplaceHTMLTags(text)
    cleanText= ReplaceNumeric(cleaText)
    cleanText= ReplaceSpecialCharacters(cleaText)
```

Comment: You can create own pipeline or organize your calls as fluent api, but it's opinion based

Comment: In view of performance it's prettys expensive to iterate and assign `string` 3 times, what could also be done in one iteration. e.g. `Replace(string input, bool htmlTag, bool numeric, bool specialChar)`

Comment: This will overly complicated a small and simple task that can be achieved with regex.

Comment: @AndréSanson, yes your correct,but there are replace methods that are coming in which is much more complicated than the 3 examples mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a good use of a strategy pattern. 
This will help you choose an algorithm at run time like HtmlReplacementBehaviour, NumericReplacementBehaviour .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

Alternatively this can also be done by leveraging Builder, You can setup a builder like

```
var replacementPlan = new ReplacementBuilder(ReplaceHTMLTags ).Add(ReplaceSpecialCharacters).Add(ReplaceNumeric);
```

Later you execute the replace method that iteratively calls the various replace logic.

Comment: Thank you. considering also the Pipeline pattern.

Comment: If this answer was helpful kindly remove the downvote . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create a string extension method for each of your replaces.

```
public static class MyStringExtension
{
    public static string ReplaceHTMLTags(this string text)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

this will allow you to chain them together like

```
text.ReplaceHTMLTags().ReplaceNumeric().ReplaceSpecialCharacters()
```